# How to give cornerRadius for UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer, cornerradius

I created a rectangle using following code and now I need to rounded the corners of this rectangle. but I can't find a property called layer.cornerRadius, can anyone help me ?

```
class OvalLayer: CAShapeLayer {

    let animationDuration: CFTimeInterval = 0.3

    override init() {
        super.init()
        fillColor = Colors.green.CGColor
        path = ovalPathSmall.CGPath
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    var ovalPathStart: UIBezierPath {
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))

        return path
    }
}
```

Comment: u can use UIBezierPath itself while drawing to make corner radius

Comment: Since you are using **UIBezierPath** you need to draw rounded corner using UIBezierPath only. Check [this](http://ronnqvi.st/thinking-like-a-bzier-path/) out, it will help you what's needed.

Comment: @iphonic Can you please send me the link which you have suggested. I won't be able to open this.

Comment: @KhushbuDesai It seems they have moved it, I found a new link [here](http://ronnqvi.st/thinking-like-a-bzier-path) it is...

Comment: @iphonic can you please help me with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50541219/how-to-set-corner-radius-to-uibezierpath/50541871?noredirect=1#comment88096434_50541871

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use below method to make all corner round of view...

```
 UIBezierPath(roundedRect: anyView.bounds, cornerRadius: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
```

If you want particular corner to make round use below method.

```
 UIBezierPath(roundedRect: anyView.bounds,
        byRoundingCorners: .BottomLeft | .BottomRight,
        cornerRadius: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
```

Comment: can you please suggest rounded corners for custom shapes like star.

Comment: @LakshmiKeerthanaSiddu have you done rounded corners for star? I want to do the same. Can you please help me!

Comment: yes, I did but not with uibezierpath . i got with CGPath or otherwise you can use paint tool

Answer (score 7):

**use like this:**

```
let pathWithRadius = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:yourView.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.TopRight, .TopLeft], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0))
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.pathWithRadius = pathWithRadius.CGPath
yourView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

for All Corner Radius edit this

```
[.TopRight,.TopLeft,.BottomRight, .BottomLeft]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Objective c:**

```
UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath
    bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 153)
                 cornerRadius: 50];
```

**SWIFT :**

```
var path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 153), cornerRadius: 50)
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

use this initializer

```
let path1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect, cornerRadius: CGFloat)
```

or

```
let path1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:  CGRect, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner, cornerRadii: CGSize))
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
 UIBezierPath(roundedRect: anyView.bounds, cornerRadius: CGFloat(4.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rounded the corners of a rectangle, you can use

```
UIBezierPath(roundedRect:  CGRect, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner,
cornerRadii: CGSize)
```

But if you want to do them oval, you can't do it. That's because UIBezierPath ignore cornerRadii.height. I fixed it in my implementation.

https://github.com/BuTaJIuK-ua/UIBezierPath-Extension