# how to set cornerRadius for only top-left corner of a UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift3

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myText: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
 }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give cornerRadius for UIBezierPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053805/how-to-give-cornerradius-for-uibezierpath)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let path =  UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .topLeft, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
myText.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

You can also use in your `UILabel` class

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let path =  UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .topLeft, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

Answer (score 11):

For **iOS 11** onwards use **Masked Corners** property.

There is now a maskedCorners property for the layer. This is a CACornerMask which has four possible values for each corner:

- layerMaxXMaxYCorner - bottom right corner
- layerMaxXMinYCorner - top right corner
- layerMinXMaxYCorner - bottom left corner
- layerMinXMinYCorner - top left corner

Create an extension for better use:

```
extension UIView {

   func roundCorners(corners:CACornerMask, radius: CGFloat) {
      self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
      self.layer.maskedCorners = corners
   }
}
```

Example:

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

   override func layoutSubviews() {
      //Round left and righ top corners
      yourView.roundCorners(corners: [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner], radius: radius)
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**Try this code**

**Tested in xcode 8 and swift3**

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

**and use like this**

```
lable.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft], radius: 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for saveing my time... it worked like charm.
Easy and simple!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add these lines for seeting corner radius:

```
let radius = 15.0
 let layer = CAShapeLayer()
 let  shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: myText.frame, byRoundingCorners: ([.topLeft]), cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius ))
layer.path = shadowPath.cgPath
myText.layer.mask = layer
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out this It is working for me.

```
 var textPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: myText.bounds, byRoundingCorners: 
                (.topLeft), cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
 var textLayer = CAShapeLayer()
 textLayer.frame = myText.bounds
 textLayer.path = textPath.cgPath
 myText.layer.mask = maskLayer
```